# Keras LSTM Time Series

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a problem and at this point I'm completely lost as to how to solve it. I'm using Keras with an LSTM layer to project a time series. I'm trying to use the previous 10 data points to predict the 11th.

Here's the code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

def _load_data(data):
"""
data should be pd.DataFrame()
"""
n_prev = 10
docX, docY = [], []
for i in range(len(data)-n_prev):
    docX.append(data.iloc[i:i+n_prev].as_matrix())
    docY.append(data.iloc[i+n_prev].as_matrix())
if not docX:
    pass
else:
    alsX = np.array(docX)
    alsY = np.array(docY)
    return alsX, alsY

X, y = _load_data(df_test)

X_train = X[:25]
X_test = X[25:]

y_train = y[:25]
y_test = y[25:]

in_out_neurons = 2
hidden_neurons = 300
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(in_out_neurons, hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(hidden_neurons, in_out_neurons))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, validation_split=0.05)

predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

So I'm taking the input data (a two column dataframe), creating X which is an n by 10 by 2 array, and y which is an n by 2 array which is one step ahead of the last row in each array of X (labeling the data with the point directly ahead of it.

predicted is returning

```
[[ 7.56940445,  5.61719704],
[ 7.57328357,  5.62709032],
[ 7.56728049,  5.61216415],
[ 7.55060187,  5.60573629],
[ 7.56717342,  5.61548522],
[ 7.55866942,  5.59696181],
[ 7.57325984,  5.63150951]]
```

but I should be getting

```
[[ 73,  48],
[ 74,  42],
[ 91,  51],
[102,  64],
[109,  63],
[ 93,  65],
[ 92,  58]]
```

The original data set only has 42 rows, so I'm wondering if there just isn't enough there to work with? Or am I missing a key step in the modeling process maybe? I've seen some examples using Embedding layers etc, is that something I should be looking at?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 42 rows is likely not enough for a neural network. At 11 time steps that only gives you about 4 completely distinct examples. Usually neural network datasets start with thousands of examples, depending on how hard the learning task is.

Comment: may I ask what version of keras you were using when you wrote this code? It seems that the update screwed everything up and this has been the best resource for me so far. I'm voting up for you and giving you a star.

Comment: Ryan were you able to get this running? If so, would you mind sharing your code so we can learn from it? I've been reading through a some broken tutorials (like those linked in Victor's answer below) and a bunch of keras issues on Github, but to no avail.

Comment: I hate the community around LSTM, none of you ever explicits anything. What is the initial shapeof the data? What should be the final?

Answer (score 14):

#### Hey Ryan!

I know it's late but I just came across your question hope it's not too late or that you still find some knowledge here.

**First** of all, Stackoverflow may not be the best place for this kind of question. First reason to that is you have a conceptual question that is not this site's purpose. Moreover your code runs so it's not even a matter of general programming. **Have a look at [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)**.

**Second** from what I see there is no conceptual error. You're using everything necessary that is:

- lstm with propper dimensions
- `return_sequences=false` just before your `Dense` layer
- linear activation for your output
- `mse` cost/loss/objective function

**Third** I however find it extremely unlikely that your network learns anything with so few pieces of data. You have to understand that you have less data than parameters here! For the great majority of supervised learning algorithm, the first thing you need is not a good model, it's good data. You can not learn from so few examples, especially not with a complex model such as LSTM networks.

**Fourth** It seems like your target data is made of relatively high values. First step of pre-processing here could be to standardize the data : center it around zero - that is translate your data by its mean - and rescale by ists standard deviation. This really helps learning!

**Fifth** In general here are a few things you should look into to improve learning and reduce overfitting :

- [Dropout](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf)
- [Batch Normalization](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf)
- Other optimizer (such as [Adam](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980))
- [Gradient clipping](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5063v2.pdf)
- [Random hyper parameter search](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf)
- (This is not exhaustive, if you're reading this and think something should be added, comment it so it's useful for future readers!)

**Last but NOT least** I suggest you look at this [tutorial on Github](http://vict0rsch.github.io/tutorials), especially the [recurrent tutorial for time series with keras](http://vict0rsch.github.io/tutorials/keras/recurrent).

PS: Daniel Hnyk updated his [post](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/) ;)

Comment: Victor - I am curious if you have seen examples where more than 1 series (perhaps multiple series) can be input for prediction? Something like your tutorial but with additional data such as day of the week, flags for holidays etc?

Comment: I guess you could try from the example in the tutorial to load other columns of the data instead of simply running on the global power of the household. There is nothing that theoretically stands between your problem and the one in the tutorial. Networks are made to take several inputs, especially several dimensions. It could help you to take a look at this part of the tutorial regarding dimensions : https://github.com/Vict0rSch/deep_learning/blob/master/recurrent.md

Sorry for the late answer, I'm currently travelling in Asia :)

Comment: @VictorSmt thanks for the links. The [Daniel Hynk](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/) post is updated to say it doesn't work and that he can't really help with people's LSTM questions :/
Do you know of other tutorials or examples of keras LSTM for time-series prediction?